# google chart animation doesn't work

Tags: animation, google-visualization

I am trying to make animations work in google charts. For some reason animation doesn't trigger.

Its pretty simple code. I would appreciate any help.

```
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);
      function drawChart() {



        var options = {
      width: 400,
      height: 240,
      animation:{
        'duration': 5000,
        'easing': 'out',
      },
      vAxis: {minValue:0, maxValue:100}
    };
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

var ch=0;
    function change(){
        if(ch==0){
                  data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     1],
          ['Eat',      20],
          ['Commute',  20],
          ['Watch TV', 20],
          ['Sleep',    17]
        ]);
            ch=1;
        }
        else if(ch==1){
            data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     10],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  12],
          ['Watch TV', 24],
          ['Sleep',    47]
        ]);
            ch=0;
        }
        drawChart();
    }
```

full code is on below JSFIddle

https://jsfiddle.net/hjnufh0o/

Answer (score 3):

You're recreating the chart object everytime you call `drawChart()` which has the effect of destroying the existing chart and building a new one - so there is nothing to animate between.

https://jsfiddle.net/2foeopyv/

I've pulled out the declarations for `chart` and `options` from the `drawChart()` section, so its now updating the chart rather than trying to recreate it.

Comment: Thanks a ton for catching my stupid mistake. Any idea why animations doesn't work with PieCharts? in this example bar chart works fine but as soon as i change var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('piechart')); with var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart')); The animations stops working.

Comment: No worries - according to https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation#supported-modifications PieCharts aren't supported when it comes to animations ( you can see at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery as well that PieCharts are one of the only standard charts that doesn't animate or redraw itself)